# Add all the items of a slice into a channel

Tags: go, slice, channel

In Go, is there a more idiomatic way to add all of the elements of an array/slice into a channel than the following?

```golang
ch := make(chan string)
values := []string{"lol", "cat", "lolcat"}

go func() {
    for _, v := range values {
        ch <- v
    }
}()
```

I was looking for something like `ch <- values...` but that is rejected by the compiler.

Comment: No. (nothing else to add, just to meet min length)

Comment: I have something to add - if you wanted to write a utility function to do that, you'd have to repeat it for any type of channel and data type you have, or use reflection tricks which might make your code cleaner if you're repeating this often, but will be slow and make your program less predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until [iterators](https://github.com/golang/go/discussions/54245) will come along, yes, the code you wrote is as idiomatic as it gets. I have it packaged for reuse as something like this in codebases I work on:

```golang
// ToChan returns a channel containing all elements in the slice s.
// The channel is closed when all elements are consumed from the channel.
func ToChan[T any](s []T) <-chan T {
    ch := make(chan T, len(s))
    for _, e := range s {
        ch <- e
    }
    close(ch)
    return ch
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/c5v4df_M1IG

Answer (score 1):

A `for`/`range` loop is the idiomatic way to send all of the elements of a slice to a channel:

```golang
for _, v := range values {
    ch <- v
}
```

It is not necessary to run the `for` loop in a goroutine, as shown in the question.

Comment: In the example, it is necessary to write the values into the channel in a goroutine because the buffer size of the channel is less than the size of the slice. In the example, the channel is a local variable, so any consumption of the channel would happen after the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a chan of string arrays, unless you absolutely want to keep a chan of strings :

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan []string)
    values := []string{"lol", "cat", "lolcat"}

    go func() {
            ch <- values
    }()

    fmt.Printf("Values : %+v\n", <-ch)
}
```